# Как сделать нумерацию элементов в списке?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как лучше в моем примере написать функцию для нумерации элементов? Нужно чтобы когда удаляешь, или добавляешь элемент в список, нумерация была всегда правильная ( чтобы учитывались удаленные или добавленные элементы). Также нужно учитывать, что количество списков может быть много

```js
let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
let block1 = document.getElementById("block1");
let block2 = document.getElementById("block2");
for (let i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {
 deleteBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(el){
   el.target.parentNode.remove();
  })
}
let addElement = document.querySelector(".btn-add1");
let addElement2 = document.querySelector(".btn-add2");
addElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
 let node = document.createElement("li");
  block1.appendChild(node);
})
addElement2.addEventListener("click", function(){
 let node = document.createElement("li");
  block2.appendChild(node);
})
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
li {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #3498db;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2980b9;
}
span.delete {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span.delete:hover {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
 <ul id="block1">
   <li>1 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>2 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>3 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>4 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>5 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
 </ul>
 <ul id="block2">
   <li>1 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>2 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>3 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>4 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
   <li>5 <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
 </ul>
<button class="btn-add1">Добавить в 1 блок</button>

<button class="btn-add2">Добавить в 2 блок</button>
```

Comment: таки используй `ol`, вместо `ul`

Comment: таки да, плюс ol { list-style-type: none; counter-reset: liCounter; } ol > li:before { counter-increment: liCounter; content:counter(liCounter); } - для "стилизации", раз уж цифры без точки должны быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если обязательно нужно решение на JS, то можно сделать так (также добавил обработчик удаления добавляемой строки):

```js
let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
let block1 = document.getElementById("block1");
let block2 = document.getElementById("block2");
for (let i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {
  deleteBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(el) {
    el.target.parentNode.remove();
    setNumbers();
  });
}
let addElement = document.querySelector(".btn-add1");
let addElement2 = document.querySelector(".btn-add2");
addElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var del = document.createElement("span"); // добавляем span
  del.classList.add('delete'); // с классом .delete
  del.textContent = 'delete'; // и текстом "delete"
  del.addEventListener('click', function(el) { // обработчик удаления строки
    el.target.parentNode.remove();
  });

  var numb = document.createElement("span"); // добавляем span
  numb.classList.add('number'); // с классом .number

  node.appendChild(numb);
  node.appendChild(del);
  block1.appendChild(node);
  setNumbers();
});
addElement2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var del = document.createElement("span"); // добавляем span
  del.classList.add('delete'); // с классом .delete
  del.textContent = 'delete'; // и текстом "delete"
  del.addEventListener('click', function(el) { // обработчик удаления строки
    el.target.parentNode.remove();
  });

  var numb = document.createElement("span"); // добавляем span
  numb.classList.add('number'); // с классом .number

  node.appendChild(numb);
  node.appendChild(del);
  block2.appendChild(node);
  setNumbers();
});

setNumbers();


function setNumbers() { // перезаписываем все номера во всех списках
  var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
  for (var a = 0; a < blocks.length; a++) {
    var lines = blocks[a].querySelectorAll('li');
    for (var b = 0; b < lines.length; b++) {
      lines[b].querySelector('.number').textContent = b + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #3498db;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2980b9;
}

span.delete {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.delete:hover {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<ul class="block" id="block1">
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="block" id="block2">
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="number"></span> <span class="delete">delete</span></li>
</ul>
<button class="btn-add1">Добавить в 1 блок</button>

<button class="btn-add2">Добавить в 2 блок</button>
```

Если же это не принципиально, я бы посоветовал вам использовать [CSS счетчики](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters):

```js
let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
let block1 = document.getElementById("block1");
let block2 = document.getElementById("block2");
for (let i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {
  deleteBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(el) {
    el.target.parentNode.remove();
  })
}
let addElement = document.querySelector(".btn-add1");
let addElement2 = document.querySelector(".btn-add2");
addElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let node = document.createElement("li");
  block1.appendChild(node);
})
addElement2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let node = document.createElement("li");
  block2.appendChild(node);
})
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #3498db;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2980b9;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item);
}

span.delete {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.delete:hover {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<ul id="block1">
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
</ul>
<ul id="block2">
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
  <li><span class="delete">delete</span></li>
</ul>
<button class="btn-add1">Добавить в 1 блок</button>

<button class="btn-add2">Добавить в 2 блок</button>
```